# Create nested dictionary on the fly in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Trying to understand how to create nested dictionaries on the fly. Ideally my dictionary would look something like:

```
mydict = { 'Message 114861156': { 'email': ['user1@domain.com', 'user2@domain.com'] }, { 'status': 'Queued mail for delivery' }}
```

Here's what i have so far:

```
sampledata = "Message 114861156 to user1@domain.com user2@domain.com  [InternalId=260927844] Queued mail for delivery'."

makedict(sampledata)

def makedict(results):
  newdict = {}
  for item in results:
    msgid = re.search(r'Message \d+', item)
    msgid = msgid.group()
    newdict[msgid]['emails'] = re.findall(r'\w+@\w+\.\w+', item)
    newdict[msgid]['status'] = re.findall(r'Queued mail for delivery', item)
```

has the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wildfires.py", line 57, in <module>
    striptheshit(q_result)
  File "wildfires.py", line 47, in striptheshit
    newdict[msgid]['emails'] = re.findall(r'\w+@\w+\.\w+', item)
KeyError: 'Message 114861156'
```

How do you make a nested dictionary like this on the fly?

Comment: FYI, legal email addresses can match a heck of a lot more patterns than `r'\w+@\w+\.\w+'`. If you're not in a constrained environment (all e-mail addresses are on some corporate domain), that regex is no good. You can [read more here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) (it includes a "mostly sufficient" regex and an RFC compliant insane regex).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`dict.setdefault` is a good tool, so is `collections.defaultdict`

Your problem right now is that `newdict` is an empty dictionary, so `newdict[msgid]` refers to a non-existent key. This works when assigning things (`newdict[msgid] = "foo"`), however since `newdict[msgid]` isn't set to anything *originally*, when you try to index it you get a `KeyError`.

`dict.setdefault` lets you sidestep that by initially saying "If `msgid` exists in `newdict`, give me its value. If not, set its value to `{}` and give me that instead.

```
def makedict(results):
    newdict = {}
    for item in results:
        msgid = re.search(r'Message \d+', item).group()
        newdict.setdefault(msgid, {})['emails'] = ...
        newdict[msgid]['status'] = ...
        # Now you KNOW that newdict[msgid] is there, 'cuz you just created it if not!
```

Using `collections.defaultdict` saves you the step of calling `dict.setdefault`. A `defaultdict` is initialized with a function to call that produces a container that any non-existent key gets assigned as a value, e.g.

```
from collections import defaultdict

foo = defaultdict(list)
# foo is now a dictionary object whose every new key is `list()`
foo["bar"].append(1)  # foo["bar"] becomes a list when it's called, so we can append immediately
```

You can use this to say "Hey if I talk to you about a new msgid, I want it to be a new dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def makedict(results):
    newdict = defaultdict(dict)
    for item in results:
        msgid = re.search(r'Message \d+', item).group()
        newdict[msgid]['emails'] = ...
        newdict[msgid]['status'] = ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Found what I was looking for in this regard at  https://quanttype.net/posts/2016-03-29-defaultdicts-all-the-way-down.html

```
def fix(f):
    return lambda *args, **kwargs: f(fix(f), *args, **kwargs)

>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = fix(defaultdict)()
>>> d["a"]["b"]["c"]
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x105c4bed8>, {})
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to create `newdict[msgid]` as an empty dictionary before storing items in it.

```
newdict[msgid] = {}
```

Comment: unless `newdict[msgid]` already exists, then you blanked out data.

Comment: _before storing items in it_